# Email an html form and submit it to the server at the same time

Tags: php, html, forms

this is probably rather simple, but I didn't really find anything online yet.

What I want to do is make a html form with the action="MAILTO:..." tag, so that the user can send a mail with the data filled in. I know how to do this.
What I also want is that the same data simultanously goes to a php script that stores it in a database. I also know how to do that (the script part, that is).

What I don't know is how to do both if the user clicks the submit button. So, user clicks, gets a mail that he/she can edit and then send, and at the same time, the form data goes to a script that stores the data in a database. They basically can fill in what they want, or leave fields blank, so I don't need to do any checking on content (except for safety reasons, of course).

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a mailing script (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead of mailto - that way you can save the data to the database and then send the mail.

Comment: You can't rely on a user's mail agent doing hardly anything other than open up with the target address in the "To:" line.

Comment: Hi Jay, I know I can do that, it's not what I want to do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: well you don't have an option, the method you described is simply not possible, and MAILTO is a bad idea regardless

Comment: Seems I do have the option Dagon :-)
The answers of both Lupin and user2751809 prove you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using javascript and ajax like this (with jquery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendData(){
               var request = $.ajax({
                  url: "yourApp.php",
                  data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                  type: 'POST'
               });

            request.done(function(){
                  $("#myform").submit();
             });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform" action="MAILTO:yourDestination@mail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
            E-mail:<br>
            <input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
            Comment:<br>
            <input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendData()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This way you will send your data to your application and then email it

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Works like a marvel!

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand you want both actions to happen upon submit, the problem is that using the MAILTO action in a form is on the client side and posting the data to  PHP script is on the server side and you cant have 2 actions just in HTML (assuming that you want the mail to be opened and displayed to the user). In order to do that i would suggest using JS, keep the action of the form as MAILTO, add an event for the form submission, and before you submit the form - which will open the email - run an AJAX call to post the data.

You can also have the form with one action and upon submission just create a 'fake' new form with same data but different action attribute and submit it. Just remember that submitting a form to a page will reload the page.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the way to go!

Comment: Happy to hear this helped